# Join and select column with max value

Tags: sql, oracle, max, inner-join

I am working on two tables in Oracle, TABLE_A containing unique IDs and Balance (number). TABLE_B shows, for the same IDs, the specific transactions and contains the following fields: IDs (not unique), BAL, Sequence_number.
I want to check that TABLE_A.Balance is always equal to TABLE_B.Balance having Max(Sequence_number).
So I expect to have just one row for each ID.

I've tried the following, yet it does not return a unique row for each ID but multiples. Why is that?

`Select a.ID, a.Balance,b.Balance, b.sequence_number From TABLE_A a  Inner join (select ID, Balance, max(sequence_number) as sequence_number from TABLE_B group by ID, Balance) b On a.ID = B.ID Group by a.ID, a.Balance, b.Balance, b.sequence_number`

### TABLE_A

```
ID_______Balance
1_______10
2_______15
3_______50
```

### TABLE_B

```
ID____Balance____Sequence_number
1_______19_______1
1_______75_______2
1_______10_______3
2_______39_______1
2_______15_______2
3_______120_______1
3_______89_______2
3_______57_______3
3_______50_______4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select a.*, b.balance
from a left join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by sequence_number desc) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on b.id = a.id and b.seqnum = 1;
```

I'm not quite sure what you want to compare, but this returns every row in `a` with the row in `b` that has the highest sequence number.

Comment: I've tried it but it does not return a single row for each ID with max(sequence_number) but multiple rows for each ID ordered by sequence_number...

Comment: @SalvatoreVitale . . . This returns exactly the rows in table `A`.  If you are getting duplicates that is because `A` has duplicates or you are not running this query.  Note that `seqnum` is not `sequence_number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number()over() window function to get the row having ID wise highest sequence_number.

Schema:

> ```
> create table TABLE_A(ID int, Balance int);
> insert into TABLE_A values(1,10);
> insert into TABLE_A values(2,15);
> insert into TABLE_A values(3,50);
>
> create table TABLE_B (ID int , Balance int,Sequence_number int);
> insert into TABLE_B values(1,19,1);
> insert into TABLE_B values(1,75,2);
> insert into TABLE_B values(1,10,3);
> insert into TABLE_B values(2,39,1);
> insert into TABLE_B values(2,15,2);
> insert into TABLE_B values(3,120,1);
> insert into TABLE_B values(3,89,2);
> insert into TABLE_B values(3,57,3);
> insert into TABLE_B values(3,50,4);
> GO
> ```

Query:

> ```
>     with cte as 
>                (
>                select id, balance, sequence_number, row_number()over (partition by id order by sequence_number desc)rnk from table_b
>                )
>     Select a.ID, a.Balance,b.Balance,  b.sequence_number From TABLE_A a  
>     Inner join cte b on a.id=b.id and rnk=1;
> GO
> ```

Output:

> | ID | Balance | Balance | sequence_number |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 10 | 10 | 3 |
> | 2 | 15 | 15 | 2 |
> | 3 | 50 | 50 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5833eeea3536f188a4f054243174a5df)*

Comment: I have revised my answer. Please check now.